# No internet while running application in android emulator

Tags: android-emulator

I get internet access on the browser but when i run the application, the application doesnt get internet. I have used internet permissions.
Actually the problem is because of proxy settings.
Early there was no internet connectivity on the browser, but later I set the proxy in APN and internet started working on the browser. But the application doesnt get internet.
Any solution for this?

Comment: How is your app connecting to the internet? Raw sockets, WebView, AndroidHttpConnection, something else?

Comment: httpConnection and webview both. The application fetches RSS feeds from the server.

Answer (score 1):

** EDITED Apr 13th 2010 **
To get the proxy working with WebView, you [apparently](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/varunsekhri/archive/2010/09/19/android-webview-behind-proxy.aspx) need to call [WebView.enablePlatformNotifications()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#enablePlatformNotifications%28%29)

According to the HttpURLConnection docs (Proxies heading):

> **Proxies**
>
> By default, this class will connect
>   directly to the origin server. It can
>   also connect via an HTTP or SOCKS
>   proxy. To use a proxy, use
>   URL.openConnection(Proxy) when
>   creating the connection.

You should be able to enable proxy use by setting the system properties described [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/ProxySelector.html), however this may not work on Android - the  [bug report on Proxy support](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9126) doesn't go into much detail on where the bug is (e.g. property not set vs property not used)

Proxy use can also be controlled using [ProxySelectorRoutePlanner](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/impl/conn/ProxySelectorRoutePlanner.html), which is used by [AbstractHttpClient.setRoutePlanner](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/impl/client/AbstractHttpClient.html#setRoutePlanner%28org.apache.http.conn.routing.HttpRoutePlanner%29). Unfortunately, this means re-writing the httpConnection code to use [DefaultHttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html)

Hope this helps,

Phil Lello

Comment: Thanks for the help, but its not working. It works at my home but it doesnt work at my work place since it is under proxy. I need a way around the proxy.

Comment: Are you saying that if you call WebView.enablePlatformNotifications, the WebView still doesn't use the proxy defined with the APN? I'll update my answer for further suggestions on the httpConnection.

Comment: Okay the webview is working now. But I am still not getting the xml feeds from the internet. The application further uses facbook and twitter apis. No internet over there aswell. Error i get is Host is unresolved

Comment: I've done a final edit on my answer, I can't easily set up a proxy for testing in my environment, so need to bow out now. Hope you get this resolved.